# Parse Dashboard Setup

Tags: parse-platform

As you all know, Parse will be fully retired on January 28th, 2017. Unfortunately i don't have account on parse.

So i have done parse-server setup at heroku and mongoDB on mongoLab.

Parse-server is working fine. But i don't know how to access parse like Dashboard.

See this picture

[image]

Did parse also made dashboard code public? if yes where it is?
And how can i setup this dashboard.

Comment: I would recommend you could setup a parse-server and parse-dashboard on your laptop or on your development server and then push when you have tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse has just released the source code for Dashboard. [Link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard)

Now you can deploy it at your own server.